# django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgis-container" to address

Tags: django, docker, pycharm

I am trying to build an image in django that will later be deployed on a digitalocean droplet with my own domain name. I am currently trying to get rid of an issue that I believe is affecting my progress in relation to my local postgis container. I have a container named: postgis-container in the network: awm. After I run:

```
 python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgis-container" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I was told by my lecturer to use the network alias for the ALLOWED_HOSTS field in my settings.py but it didn't make any difference. I put a comment to the right hand side of the possible offending line.

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for AdvancedWebMapping project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
import socket
from pathlib import Path
import docker_config
from whitenoise.storage import CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = docker_config.SECRET_KEY

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'world',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'AdvancedWebMapping.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'AdvancedWebMapping.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'gis',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': 'docker',
        'PASSWORD': 'docker',
        'PORT': '25432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

if socket.gethostname() =="matthew@acer":
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "localhost"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 25432
else:
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "postgis-container" # offending line?
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 5432

# Set DEPLOY_SECURE to True only for LIVE deployment
if docker_config.DEPLOY_SECURE:
    DEBUG = False
    TEMPLATES[0]["OPTIONS"]["debug"] = False
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.matthewmawm.xyz', 'localhost', '209.97.133.19']
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
else:
    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATES[0]["OPTIONS"]["debug"] = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', ]
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

how I created the postgis container (docker):

```
sudo docker create --name postgis-container --network awm --network-alias postgis-container -t -p 25432:5432 -v name_of_volume:/var/lib/postgresql kartoza/postgis
```

Comment: is your app also in docker container and on same network, if not you should use docker container ip or route it to localhost

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/

Comment: Using a dockerfile to build an image which I then use to create the django-container with the following commands: docker build -t geodjango .  docker create --name django-container --network awm --network-alias django-container -t -p 40001:8001 geodjango. The " ." after the build command is intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own mistake. My hostname was incorrect at socket.gethostname().